# Total Grant Amount or Amount from Government on CV

Tags: funding, cv

There are several questions on here that talk about adding dollar amounts of grants onto CV's. The consensus has been that it is a good idea.

I just won a national fellowship from the government to fund me. The funding amount is X units of currency. One of the contingencies is that, if successful, the university throws in X/5 and then the UK government funds 4X/5.  I am not sure if I should put X or 4X/5.

The offer letter states X, so it makes sense to put that number on there; however, the publicly available amount that the government posts on their website is the 4X/5 total. I am fearful that if I put X then people will fact-check and see the 4X/5 amount and think that I'm exaggerating. Which is the appropriate number to put on a CV?

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 9):

In the US, this kind of arrangement is called "cost sharing." Under current rules federal agencies are no longer allowed to require cost sharing and institutions cannot propose cost sharing, although this was sometimes required in the past.

The way to describe this in a CV would normally be to give the amount of the award as one number, plus the amount of cost share as a second number.

e.g.

B. Borchers.  Searching for Tribbles in the Oort Cloud.  Extra Terrestrial Biology Funding Agency, 2015-2017.  $100,000 award plus $20,000 in institutional cost sharing.

Comment: In the end, the total amount is what you got for your work, where it came from is less relevant.

Comment: See the OP's question:  the amount listed on the government website is 4x/5.  My formulation above is consistent with that and also explains the total amount of funding.  If the OP simply listed "x", then anyone checking this against the database would find a discrepancy.

Comment: Similar issues occur when "supplementary funds" are awarded on top of the original grant award.